# Deploying on google App Engine : An error occurred: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGABRT Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGABRT

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, ffmpeg

I wrote a node-js api, with node-js and fluent-ffmpeg :

```
'use strict';
require('babel-register');
const path = require('path');    
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
```

[...]

```
var infs = new ffmpeg

infs.addInput(doc.data().url).outputOptions([
            '-preset slow', '-g 48', '-sc_threshold 0',
            '-map 0:0', '-map 0:1', '-map 0:0', '-map 0:1',
            '-s:v:0 1280x720', '-c:v:0 libx264', '-b:v:0 2000k',
            // "-var_stream_map", "'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1'",
            '-master_pl_name ./' + req.params.id + '/master' + req.params.id + '.m3u8',
            '-f hls', '-hls_time 6', '-hls_list_size 0',
            '-hls_segment_filename ./' + req.params.id + '/fileSequence|' + req.params.id + '|%d|v%v.ts',
            '-max_muxing_queue_size 1024',
        ]).output('./' + req.params.id + '/video' + req.params.id + '.m3u8')
            .on('start', function (commandLine) {
                console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
            })
            .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message, err, stderr);
            })
            .on('progress', function (progress) {
                console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
            })
            .on('end', function (err, stdout, stderr) {

                console.log('Finished processing!' /*, err, stdout, stderr*/)
            })
            .run()
        res.status(200).send('GG').end();
    } 
   });
```

[...]

That work with

> node app.js

on my macbook pro, but when i do

> gcloud app deploy

and I call the public url, I have this logs :

```
Processing: undefined% done
An error occurred: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGABRT Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGABRT
```

Here is my app.yaml :

```
    # Copyright 2017, Google, Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START gae_flex_quickstart_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 6
  disk_size_gb: 30

# [END gae_flex_quickstart_yaml]
```

[image]

How can I do to deploy correctly my node-js api on google app engine ?

Thank's in advance.

Jérémy.

Comment: As the error message pointed out 'signal SIGABRT ' sent to ffmpeg, Normally signal SIGABRT means there is runtime error.  please check if the App Engine size fit?

Comment: Yes, you can see the ressources in app.yaml

Comment: Can you flag [--verbosity](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) to debug? Run 'gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug' and add the debug information here for me to better understand the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

We do not have information about what exactly is `doc.data().url`, however this will be something you are getting from db document. So looking into `addInput` [documentation](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#specifying-inputs), I guess, it has to be some local file name. Local file name is, as well, argument of `output` method.

This will work on your local environment, however when you deal with files in App Engine you have to use some storage services which is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-third-party-databases).

Comment: doc.data().url is a the url of my mp4 in google cloud storage In my complete code, after the conversion, I upload all the .ts files to google cloud storage, but here the conversion don't work !

Comment: Does `addInput` works with url's? According to the documentation it should be path or path pattern or readable stream...

Comment: Yes. And it work on my MacBook Pro with node app.js

Answer (score -1):

According to [the library documentation](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#fluent-ffmpeg-api-for-nodejs-):

> In order to be able to use this module, make sure you have ffmpeg
> installed on your system (including all necessary encoding libraries
> like libmp3lame or libx264).

Checking the default node container (that you're using, according to the `app.yaml`), I'm not sure [the right dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#dependencies) come pre-installed.

You can check by going to a deployed instance, enable debugging, and SSHing into it. You can follow the process detailed in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/debugging-an-instance).

If all the required dependencies are not pre-installed, you'll have to [build a custom container](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) for GAE flex.

Since the node library `fluent-ffmpeg` is just running the local command ([you can check in the code of the library](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/blob/12667091eeea09b0d6a55b87eb886aa131178608/lib/utils.js#L4)), it can be that your local computer has everything installed, but it's missing components in the built image.

The fact that you're testing with `node app.js` (i.e. not in a build container, but with the local node), gives more credit to this idea.

Comment: Frmpeg is installed by default on Google app engine. Any other ideas.?

Comment: My question was more about the codecs than the command itself. The fact that the error was thrown by `ffmpeg` itself gave me a clue that the command existed. It just seems like the command can't do what you're asking it to do. That's why I suggested SSHing and testing from within the instance to better understand the issue.

Comment: Yes, but what test ?

Comment: Once SHH'd into the instance, enter the app container and try to run the `ffmpeg` command by hand on the CLI. This should either work (and there is something wrong with the app), or fail with a more verbose error.

Comment: I don't find how to connect to my app engine instance. How can I do that ?

Comment: I included the link on my answer: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/debugging-an-instance

Comment: I did that but there is an error. I added it to my question

Comment: Those are bash errors. Try to put the URLs in quotation marks in order to avoid bash understanding it as keywords (i.e. the `&` in the URL is creating a background process).

Comment: Yes, but it is the same answer